# Is it possible to link an external stylesheet, exclusively within a specific single post template?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, css

**SOLUTION**

Big shoutout to the wonderful SallyM, who answered this very succinctly in the comments of this post.

If it helps anybody, here's the code that I used.

*Note: Replace the //CONTENT// with your own site content*

```
function include_template_specific_css() {
if (is_page_template('//TEMPLATEFILENAMEWITHDIRECTORY//.php'))
    wp_enqueue_style('//CSSFILENAME//', get_template_directory_uri().'//CSSFILEURL//.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_template_specific_css');
```

Good luck!

**/SOLUTION**

I'm attempting to call a specific stylesheet within the php of a new post template (one of four).

The stylesheet is '*Featured-Article.css*'. 
The template file is '*Featured-Article.php*'.

Code I've attempted to place within the template includes:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('Featured-Article', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'assets/css/Featured-Article.css',array('style')); ?>
```

and

```
<style> <?php include 'assets/css/Featured-Article.css'; ?> </style>
```

I'm wondering whether this is even possible at this point, short of meddling with functions.php to create a "if (is_page_template('Featured-Article.php')) etc" - something substantially beyond my ability!

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

It looks like the consensus is that such a callback must take place from within a theme's functions.php file. To this end, here's a draft code snippet that I'd hope might accomplish our aim, however sadly didn't work.

```
function //theme//_include_page_specific_css() {
if (is_page_template('Featured-Article.php'))
    wp_enqueue_style('Featured-Article', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/Featured-Article.css'); }


add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'Featured-Article');
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE 2 - SOLVED**

Big shoutout to the wonderful SallyM, who answered this very succinctly in the comments of this post.

If it helps anybody, here's the code that I used.

*Note: Replace the //CONTENT// with your own site content*

```
function include_template_specific_css() {
if (is_page_template('//TEMPLATEFILENAMEWITHDIRECTORY//.php'))
    wp_enqueue_style('//CSSFILENAME//', get_template_directory_uri().'//CSSFILEURL//.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_template_specific_css');
```

Good luck!

Comment: "Meddling" in functions.php with `is_page_template()` would be the correct way to do this.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I hear it - meddling is a verb that probably overstates my ability to deal with PHP, if anything. Haha. 
How would you recommend approaching it? A draft I'd been working on looks like this:

 `if ( is_page_template('Featured-Article.php')) {
       function //themename//_include_page_specific_css() {
  wp_enqueue_style('Featured-Article', get_template_directory_uri().'assets/css/Featured-Article.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Featured-Article');
    }` however this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @PeterMatthews The callback name is incorrect: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Featured-Article')`. The `is_page_template()` check should also be done from inside the callback. And `get_template_directory_uri()` doesn't include the ending slash (`/`), so you should add it manually: `get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/Featured-Article.css'`

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks so much for your feedback! I took into account your advice, and came up with this: `function //theme//_include_page_specific_css() {
 if (is_page_template('Featured-Article.php'))
  wp_enqueue_style('Featured-Article', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/assets/css/Featured-Article.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'Featured-Article');
 }` unfortunately, still no joy. Any ideas? :)

Comment: The second parameter for `add_action` should be a function name (or a lambda, or a tuple with class and function), and that function is where you enqueue the script.

Comment: (That said I'm surprised putting the enqueue script on the page template didn't work, assuming you put it at the top before you call get_header(). Not that that's really the way to do to this.)

Comment: @Rup it's an interesting one, thanks for your comment. I tried Enqueue-ing prior to calling the header, but it only ever resulted in a problem with page load (I ran a debugger on the code, which cited that it expected $EOF) or, when an end of file was written, had no effect/styling on the template's HTML :/ . Regarding the `add_action`, I've had trouble conjugating it as a function. How would you write it as a function?

Comment: @PeterMatthews `function //theme//_include_page_specific_css() {` - that produces a syntax error. You also have an unwanted `}` after the `add_action()` call. And you still didn't use the correct callback/function name - `add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'Featured-Article');` - `Featured-Article` is not a valid function name. And the hook name is not `wp_enqueue_style`; it's `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: @SallyCJ. Thanks so much for your tips! I'm fortunate to have your help, especially re. the syntax (as I'm sure you can see, PHP is not my forte!). I should clarify, where `//theme//` is in my supplied code, I'm inserting the name of my theme. In reality, I'm using the theme Neve, so my code actually reads `neve_include_page_specific_css`. Regarding the callback, I'd attempted it with just `add_action('wp_enqueue_style');` and originally `add_action('wp_enqueue_script');` to no effect, am I missing something?

Comment: `add_action( 'hook name', 'function name' )` - that's the basic syntax of `add_action()`. So if the function name is `neve_include_page_specific_css`, then the proper syntax is `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'neve_include_page_specific_css' )`

Comment: @SallyCJ you are amazing. Thank you so much for your patience, especially regarding the callback syntax which I really should have known already. Made my day, and made this project. Thank you!